# C++: Recursive function for variations with repetitions, ordered by amount of different letters

Tags: c++, recursion, graph

I have a function that generates variations like this: 111, 112, ..., 133, 211, 212, ..., 233, 311, ..., 333. Length of generated sequences always matches length of dictionary; with 4 symbols it'd be 1111 to 4444.

This is done in a brute force algorithm for graph coloring. We're trying to find the right sequence that has as less different colors as possible, i.e. if both 12343 and 12321 are solutions, we'd prefer the latter.

Right now I go and check each and every sequence if it’s right, and then store the best result in process. It’s not really a good code.

So professor asked me to write a function that generates variations in specific order. These sequences should come ordered by their amount of different numbers, like this: 111, 222, 333; 112, 113, 121, …, 323; 123, 213. In this case, if we found out that, say, 121 is right, we just stop, because we already know that it’s the best solution.

The idea is to skip as much sequence checks as possible so the code would run faster. Please help :)

Right now I use this code:

init function

```
std::vector<int> res; //contains the "alphabet"
res.reserve(V);
for (int i = V - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    res.push_back(i);
}

std::vector<int> index(res.size());
std::vector<int> bestresult(V); //here goes the best answer if it's found
for (int i = V - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    bestresult.push_back(i);
}
int bestcolors = V;
permutate(res, index, 0, bestresult, bestcolors);

result = bestresult;
```

permutate:

```
void Graph::permutate(const std::vector<int>& s, std::vector<int>& index, std::size_t depth, std::vector<int>& bestres, int &lowestAmountOfColors)
{
if (depth == s.size()) {
    //doing all needed checks and saving bestresult here;

    return;
}

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
    index[depth] = i;
    permutate(s, index, depth + 1, bestres, lowestAmountOfColors);
}
}
```

How can I alter these functions?

Comment: I have a question. Is there any difference between the colors, so if '111' has been checked, then should you consider '222' at all? For graph coloring, I would expect the answer to be identical if you swap colors. Thus on case n, the permutations to be considered must include at least one of 1, 2, ... n.

Comment: I shouldn't, you're right. I wanted to mention that, but I'm not that fluent in English :)

Comment: (at least one each of)

Comment: I would consider permutations for the case of 1 color, then 2 colors, then 3 colors ... and so on. Within those permutations, I'm not immediately sure how to enforce the condition I mentioned above. Also check the edge count to see if you can get a lower or upper bound for the number of colors you need to consider.

Comment: >I would consider permutations for the case of 1 color, then 2 colors, then 3 colors... I'm not sure how to do this. The only idea I have is to simply ignore the checks if current permutation is done on a different amount of colors than we asked for.

Comment: I have what appears to be a working solution, except for next_combination (which I left alone because it is easy to find online). I'm trying to figure out how much I can post to give a good answer, but not give too much.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is to find all permutations of colors so that you can test if they are a valid graph coloring. Unfortunately, it is exponential. So we need to search the permutations in a way that we check the smallest solutions first, and we need to prune the solution space dramatically.

To find the smallest solutions first, we must limit the number of colors available, and exhaust those permutations before we grow the number of colors. Pretty simple. We just need a function that considers n colors for N vertices. The number of vertices remains fixed, but we consider n=1, then n=2, etc.

Within the function, we know that we need various combinations of 1, 2, ... n with enough repetition to get a total of N different values. So I made a vector of counts. This vector has n entries, and the values sum up to N.

For example, if we are considering three color solutions for a graph with 7 vertices, one possible count array would be {4, 3, 1} would be used to generate the candidate {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3}. Color 1 appears 4 times. Color 2 appears 3 times. Color 3 appears 1 time.

The cool thing about this counts array is that as long as it is sorted greatest to least, then its combinations cannot duplicate any other combination we have considered, because colors are interchangable. (Okay, not entirely accurate, there are some duplications when colors have the same count, but we eliminated a lot of permutations from ever being looked at, which is the whole point).

Once you reduce the counts array to an actual candidate solution, you can find all ordering using combinations, not permutations. This will generate fewer candidates. Google next_combination to find some good code showing how to do this.

When we generate the counts array, I initialized all values to 1, then added all the remaining counts to the first color. I search ALL combinations which meet the counts array. Then I get the next candidate by shifting the counts to the right in such a way that it remains sorted.

---

So to sum up, find_minimum_graph_coloring has a for loop which calls solve_for_n. That function generates all the possible counts-arrays for that value of n, and calls another function. That function checks all combinations for that counts-array.

The first for loop checks smaller numbers of colors first, so we can return immediately upon finding a solution. The counts-array notation eliminates many equivalent colorations so if we consider {1, 1, 2} then we will never try {2, 2, 1}

Comment: Incidentally, the first line is if (graph.edge_count==0) return 1; and the for loop never considers n == graph.vertex_count because we already know the answer at that point. There may be some better upper and lower bounds that you can get from just V and E.

Comment: I get the idea and I did found implementation for next_combination, although I'm not sure how to use it. What should I pass to this function so the generated sequences will match current `counts[j]`, for example?

Comment: We are still doing brute force, just with fewer repetitions. You use each instance of counts to initialize one actual array of colors. Then, in a separate function, you must test every combination of that against your actual graph to see if it is a valid graph coloring.

Comment: I found a bug/design flaw in my next_candidate generator for the counts array. It needs a DP or backtracking mechanism. But I didn't go into enough detail on my implementation to force you to make the same mistake, so hopefully you are safe. :)

Comment: I’m still trying to implement all this; little hint would be appreciated :-)

Comment: I think I've done it, albeit in some very simple way. Thanks for the ideas, they really helped)